# Display MP3 as media using an URL from a custom field

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, media

I created custom field and placed this inside the loop:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ses', true); ?>
```

But now the link is all text. I would like it to be like my theme does when I use this shortcode:

```
[media url="http://www.example.com/songname.mp3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to echo the full [Audio Tag](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3920991/HTML5-Primer-How-To-Use-the-Audio-Tag.htm) and insert the custom field MP3 address in it.

```
<?php 
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ses', true) ) {
        echo '<audio controls="controls">
                <source src="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ses', true) . '" />
                </audio>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: one little problem. now the player is in every post.

Comment: The Codex is your friend, [read the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). Answer updated :)

Comment: brasofilo, could you help me out with one last thing, now i tried to post youtube video. how can i make it visible in my site? i found youtube id code. but i want to make it with full yotube video url. thank you...

Comment: 1907, WordPress has a feature called *oEmbed* that can help you with that, search for it here or at [WordPress Forums](http://wordpress.org/tags/oembed). Hopefully, you'll be around enough time to find that this site is a great learning resource. For a better experience I suggest you read the full [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) (you'll even earn an extra badge for that :).

Comment: you are right but all sites are english. i am having hard time to understanding it. my english not that good. thats why i am asking so many questions. actualy i love reading but in turkish :)

Comment: I see... Well, this site is not a support forum, open a support request [here](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/how-to-and-troubleshooting), leave the link in this comments and I'll help you later on...

Comment: brasofilo thanks a lot. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-fields-youtube?replies=1